# csv.writerow() raising an AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

As the title says I'm getting an `AttributeError` when I use `csv.writerow()`.

I'm trying to add values into a csv file using `csv.writerow()`.

The code:

```
import csv

class File:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __add__(self, other):
        with open(self.f, mode='a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            f.writerow(str(other))
            return self.__str__()

o = File('file.csv')
s = o + 2
```

I expected the code to add a new value to csv file and separate it from the other values with a comma.
The whole line from the error report looks like this:
`AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writerow'`.

Comment: Use `writer.writerow(str(other))` **not** `f.writerow(str(other))`.

Comment: @martineau Thanks that'll work!